# Jboss Fuse Esb java.lang.outOfMemoryError exception

Tags: out-of-memory, heap-memory, apache-karaf, fuseesb, jbossfuse

i have a ESB that contains starting point  `CXF Endpoint` to `ActiveMQ` and to `web service`.But sometimes i gave this error during `Fuse` is running.Here is the log file:

```
Exception in thread "ActiveMQ Journal Checkpoint Worker" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap Space
```

What should i do for resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not already, you should increase the heap size for ServiceMix. This can be done by editing the startup script at bin/servicmix and changing the startup parameters for the Java command to a number higher than the default. Make sure to pay attention to both max heap and permgen.

Comment: Yes i did this before and it did work!Even this thanx for your answer.@Michael